# Prime numbers display and count c++

Tags: c++, count, counter, primes, counting

The code is working fine for displaying prime numbers, but I need them to be displayed and to also display the number of prime numbers.

The code is for prime numbers in a selected interval.

Here's my code:

```
bool prastevila_interval(int z, int k) //primes in interval
{
    for (int i = z; i < k; ++i){
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++){
            if (!(i % j) && (i != j))
                break;
            else if (i == j){
                cout<< i <<endl;
            }

        }
    }
return true;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() { 

                //Primes in interval
    cout<<"__________PRASTEVILA V INTERVALU__________"<<endl;

    cout << "Zacetek intervala : ";
    cin >> z;                          //starting point of interval

    cout << "Konec intervala : ";
    cin >> k;                          //ending point of interval

    cout<<"Prastevila v intervalu so: "<<endl;

    prastevila_interval(z, k) == true;

    cout <<"Stevilo prastevil na interval od "<< z 
         <<" do "<< k <<" je : "<< counter << endl;   
    // this counter is not working ---^
}
```

How to count the number of primes?

P.S. : I tried everything already and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: To count them you just have to initialize a variable with 0 and then just variable++ before the last cout. As for printing them, just store the numbers in an array and print that array using a for loop

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYONE! I managed to do it with simple 2 lines of code, which I forgot to add....

I feel like hanging myself now.. xD
Thank you (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  just need to update the counter on each prime number found.
Since your method return always true, I suggest to change it like so:

```
int prastevila_interval(int z, int k) //primes in interval
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = z; i < k; ++i){
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (!(i % j) && (i != j))
                    break;
            else if (i == j)
            {
                    cout<< i <<endl;
                    counter++;
            }
         }      
     }
return counter;
}
```

and so:

```
cout <<"Stevilo prastevil na interval od "<< z 
     <<" do "<< k <<" je : "<< prastevila_interval(z,k) << endl;
```

Note also, that this code:

```
prastevila_interval(z,k) == true;
```

doesn't do anything and generally meaningless. Your just check here whether the return value is true and don't do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you, I've done it and it's working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass a pointer or a reference to the `counter` to your function, and have it update it.

```
bool prastevila_interval(int z, int k, int& counter) //primes in interval
{
    counter = 0;
    for (int i=z; i<k; ++i){
        for (int j=2; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (!(i%j)&&(i!=j))
                break;
            else if (i == j){
                cout<< i <<endl;
                ++counter;
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Calling this will be like:

```
int counter = 0;
prastevila_interval(lo, hi, counter);
```

Another way you can do this is by having `prastevila_interval` return an `int` instead of a `bool`, which is the number of primes printed.

Comment: I've used Roman Pustylnikov's answer to solve my problem. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your function to:

```
int prastevila_interval(int z, int k) //primes in interval   
{
    int counter = 0;      

    for (int i = z; i < k; ++i){
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++){
            if (!(i % j) && (i != j))
                break;
            else if (i == j){
                counter++;
                cout<< i <<endl;
         }
    }
return counter;
}
```

and then call it in your main as:

```
int prime_number = prastevila_interval(lower_bound, upper_bound);

cout << "Number of primes:" << prime_numbers << endl;
```

Comment: I've used Roman Pustylnikov's answer to solve my problem. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a counter to your function and increment the counter with one each time you find a prime.

```
bool prastevila_interval(int z, int k, int &counter) //primes in interval
{
    for (int i=z; i<k; ++i){
            for (int j=2; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (!(i%j)&&(i!=j))
                break;
            else if (i == j)
            {
                counter++;
                cout<< i <<endl;
            }   
    }
    return true;
}
```

Initialize a counter in your main function and pass it to the function as usual.

Comment: I've used Roman Pustylnikov's answer to solve my problem. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like:

```
bool prime(int num)
{
    if (num == 2) return true;
    else
        for (int j=2; j<=sqrt(num); j++)
        {
            if ( num%j == 0)
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}

int prastevila_interval(int z, int k) //primes in interval
{
    int counter =0;
    for (int i=z; i<k; ++i)
    {
        if (prime(i))
        {
            cout<< i <<" ";
            counter++;
        }

    }
    cout<<endl;
    return counter;
}

int main()
{

    //Primes in interval
    cout<<"__________PRASTEVILA V INTERVALU__________"<<endl;
    cout<<"Zacetek intervala : ";
    cin>>z;                          //starting point of interval
    cout<<"Konec intervala : ";
    cin>>k;                          //ending point of interval
    cout<<"Prastevila v intervalu so: "<<endl;
    int counter = prastevila_interval(z,k);
    cout<<"Stevilo prastevil na interval od "<<z<<" do "<<k<<" je : "<<counter<<endl;
```

Comment: I've used Roman Pustylnikov's answer to solve my problem. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: @S-K: welcome. I think you can understand my answer. If you like it, you can give me  a up vote.

Comment: Sure, will do that! Thanks again :)

And yes, I do understand your answer and I bet I won't be making a mistake like this in the future ^^

Comment: @S-K:  Thanks :). I do this answer for your better understand. And I also can correction for your code.